# Terraform Json conditional creation

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I`m trying to create json template file for emr security configuration. Currently I have the following:

```
resource "aws_emr_security_configuration" "this" {
      name = "test-configuration"
      configuration = jsonencode({
          "EncryptionConfiguration": {
            "EnableInTransitEncryption": var.intransitencryption_enabled,
            "EnableAtRestEncryption": var.atrestencryption_enabled
            "InTransitEncryptionConfiguration": {
              "TLSCertificateConfiguration": {
                "CertificateProviderType": "PEM",
                "S3Object": var.s3_object
              }
            },
            "AtRestEncryptionConfiguration": {
              "S3EncryptionConfiguration": {
                "EncryptionMode": "SSE-KMS",
                "AwsKmsKey": var.kms_key_arn
              },
              "LocalDiskEncryptionConfiguration": {
                "EnableEbsEncryption": true,
                "EncryptionKeyProviderType": "AwsKms",
                "AwsKmsKey": var.kms_key_arn
              }
            }
          }
       })
 }
```

I want depends on var.intransitencryption_enabled variable (true or false) add or remove the following part:

```
"InTransitEncryptionConfiguration": {
  "TLSCertificateConfiguration": {
    "CertificateProviderType": "PEM",
    "S3Object": var.s3_object
  }
}
```

I tried

```
%{ if var.intransitencryption_enabled}
"InTransitEncryptionConfiguration": {
  "TLSCertificateConfiguration": {
    "CertificateProviderType": "PEM",
    "S3Object": var.s3_object
  }
}
{endif}
```

But it does not work. Does terraform have a valid decision to do that?

Comment: Tell us more about how it 'does not work'?

Comment: got the following error:
92:       %{ if var.intransitencryption_enabled}
Expected the start of an expression, but found an invalid expression token.